# Spring http API returns error 500 but error is not logged in console

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-session

I have a spring boot application, (spring 5.0.7.Release , spring boot version 2.0.3).

Where I try to login from my angular 4 app, I get an error 500

```
{"timestamp":"2018-07-13","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"org.springframework.session.MapSession.getCreationTime()Ljava/time/Instant;","path":"/security/signIn/password"}
```

But in eclipse my console show only this

> 2018-07-13 12:11:59.243 DEBUG 64187 --- [nio-9000-exec-2]
>   f.p.a.c.CustomBasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication success:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@aa6b860d:
>   Principal:
>   fr.pangeeconseil.purchase.core.domain.security.AuthenticatedUserDTO@75136264;
>   Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted
>   Authorities: SUPER_ADMINISTRATOR 2018-07-13 12:11:59.306 DEBUG 64187
>   --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST
>   request for [/error] 2018-07-13 12:11:59.311 DEBUG 64187 ---
>   [nio-9000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking
>   up handler method for path /error 2018-07-13 12:11:59.313 DEBUG 64187
>   --- [nio-9000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public
>   org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity>
>
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
>   2018-07-13 12:11:59.314 DEBUG 64187 --- [nio-9000-exec-2]
>   f.p.a.c.web.CustomWebContentInterceptor  : Looking up cache seconds
>   for [/error] 2018-07-13 12:11:59.314 DEBUG 64187 --- [nio-9000-exec-2]
>   f.p.a.c.web.CustomWebContentInterceptor  : Applying default cache
>   seconds to [/error] 2018-07-13 12:11:59.402 DEBUG 64187 ---
>   [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Written
>   [{timestamp=Fri Jul 13 12:11:59 CEST 2018, status=500, error=Internal
>   Server Error,
>   message=org.springframework.session.MapSession.getCreationTime()Ljava/time/Instant;,
>   path=/security/signIn/password}] as "application/json" using
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@305deb42]
>   2018-07-13 12:11:59.403 DEBUG 64187 --- [nio-9000-exec-2]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned
>   to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming
>   HandlerAdapter completed request handling 2018-07-13 12:11:59.404
>   DEBUG 64187 --- [nio-9000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>   : Successfully completed request

Important informations :

- we use redis session with the following reference in our gradle.build

compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.0.8.RELEASE'

compile "org.springframework.session:spring-session:1.3.3.RELEASE"

compile "org.springframework.session:spring-session-core:2.0.0.RELEASE"

compile "org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis:2.0.4.RELEASE"

- Here is our SecurityConfig : https://gist.github.com/RemiBou/fe3a28644cddf8b4e72ad9fdeb26d24e

I'm a very beginner with spring/spring boot so it might be obvious but I couldn't find anything online.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out : spring-session is obsolete, I needed to remove it, and change a few things in securityConfiguration because some classes where removed / renamed.